# Google AppMaker date validation

Tags: validation, date, google-app-maker

How to do some date validation here so that when user enter **end date** less than **start date** it will prompt error to user? Is there any built in function made by AppMaker? Thanks for sharing!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the input to a data model, you can use the **Advanced** section of the data model.

[image: 1]]

You can also achieve data validation through **Event** section or **Data Validation** section. Use the the first one to implement small scripts and the second one to hardcode rules into the app.

```
// date is not a previous date  
var date = new Date();
    if (widget.value < date) {
      alert('Invalid date');
    }

// date is not a future date  
var date = new Date();
    if (widget.value > date) {
      alert('Invalid date');
    }

// second date is not higher than first date
    if (widget.value > widget.parent.descendants.firstDate.value) {
      alert('Invalid date');
    }
```

[image: 2]]

Comment: how to alert user end date is required and cannot be empty when user had choose start date?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, you can make the date mandatory. Just click on **required** and the user will not be able to continue without the date.

Comment: I have tried with **required** but I can continue click SEARCH button and do filtering please advise. Other issue is I still stuck to prompt error if user select end date less than start date because even I had set the MaxValue, user can still continue filter and click SEARCH button. Although the results is empty but I would like to do it in a more proper way to prompt error and tell user to enter the correct information. Thanks!

Comment: The MaxValue rule will not give you the proper result, as the validation you require is a MinValue rule (Minvalue > startDate).
You can use the validation script I mentioned under "// second date is not higher than first date" instead. If you want to prevent the user from running any search, if the proper search dates haven't been set, you should implement the validation script right in the onClick event of the search button.

Comment: validation script ya ouh ok thanks! but in the script how can I prompt error if user enter end-date larger than start-date?

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from running any search, if the proper date validation hasn't been confirmed (leave the rules in the validation script), you can extend the script in the onClick event of the search button. The onClick would then look something like `if (widget.validate()) {query.run()} else {alert('Incorrect date')}` You can find more in the widget logic https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#events